# naudio audio stream to html / webpage

Tags: c#, audio-streaming, naudio

I'm looking for a way to stream microphone input to a HTML/Javascript page.

I've downloaded the **naudio** project, using the Network Chat demo, able to construct a sender and receiver and live stream audio over HTTP.

Great

I'd now like to play this stream in a html audio tag, or, via a client side  JS library

e.g.,

```
<audio controls>
      <source src="http://127.0.0.1:7080" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Can this approach work via naudio?  The above doesn't work.  I'm not sure if I am missing something small, or, if this approach will not work at all.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0):

This wont work with the network chat.
The audio stream requests chunks and downloads them.
Was just being lazy